# Tensorflow: tf.train.Feature error 'expected one of: bytes'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

all

I am trying to serialize data to a tfrecords file in tensorflow. I follow the instruction from here:
https://github.com/tensorlayer/tensorlayer/blob/master/example/tutorial_tfrecord.py

As shown in this instruction, I need to build an `example`  for each  record, and each `example` contains multiple `feature`.

However, I have problems when initializing the feature. Here is my test code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

feature_str=tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value = np.array(["a" , "b"])))

feature_int=tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.Int64List(value = np.array([32 , 24])))

feature_flo=tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.FloatList(value = np.array([32.1 , 24.1 ])))
```

However, I got following error which is countintuitive:

usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/**init**.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in 
    feature_int=tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.Int64List(value = np.array([32 , 24])))
TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected tensorflow.BytesList got tensorflow.Int64List.

I further try to use `tf.train.BytesList` for `np.array([32,24])` and got the error below:

feature_int=tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value = np.array([32 , 24])))
TypeError: 32 has type numpy.int64, but expected one of: bytes

Can anyone helpt me on this issue ? I am really confused.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to feed `bytes` to `bytes_list` instead of `string`. The following gives an example of all the three cases:

**To TFRecords:**

```
output_file = 'out.tfrecord'
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_file)

"""Build an Example proto
"""

feature = {}
feature['str'] = tf.train.Feature(
       bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value = [b"a",b"b"]))
feature['int'] = tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value = np.array([32 , 24])))
feature['flo'] = tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value = np.array([32.1 , 24.1 ])))

features = tf.train.Features(feature=feature)
example = tf.train.Example(features=features)
serialized = example.SerializeToString()
writer.write(serialized)

writer.close()
```

**Read from TFRecords:**

```
  for serialized_example in tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator('out.tfrecord'):
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.ParseFromString(serialized_example)
    print(example.features.feature['str'].bytes_list.value)
    print(np.array(example.features.feature['int'].int64_list.value))
    print(np.array(example.features.feature['flo'].float_list.value))
```

**Output:**

```
[b'a', b'b']
[32 24]
[32.09999847 24.10000038]
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you know the reason that float list value show [32.09999847 24.10000038] not [32.1 24.1]?